# How to store common data inside the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have configuration data stored within the tables like casestatustypes with columns such as statusid, name, description. How to store these kind of data in the web application, instead of hitting the database each time for retrieving the statusid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a technique known as **caching**. Basically, you build an in-memory copy of the data that you use for retrieval purposes. When you start the application, you pull from the database to create this cache. When you do an insert, update, or delete; you do it to both the cache and database.

Its easy enough to implement yourself, and there are several good libraries out there (Microsoft even has one in Enterprise Library http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc467894.aspx).

**Gotchas:**

- If the data set is large, you'll want to implement a caching strategy that doesn't hold the entire dataset in memory (libraries are useful for this).
- Since its a web-app, you need to make sure the cache isn't going to be re-created for each session.